# Smallest and Largest Days

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

*A certain rule is applied to the days expressed in the format of DD/MM/YYYY.*

---

*According to that rule,*

- *Roberto Matta was a famous painter born on the smallest day of the 20th century.*
- *Roger Federer is a famous tennis player born on the largest day of 1981.*

---

*According to the same rule,*

- ***Which country witnessed an uprising on the largest day of the 20th century?***
- ***Which are the smallest and largest days of the 21st century?***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Size appears to be related to the number of lit segments of a [seven-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display). The largest digit would be 8, implying all 7 segments are lit; the smallest, 1, implying 2 segments are lit.

> Burma/Myanmar, the [8888 Uprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8888_Uprising)

> Largest: `08/08/2088` -- segment count: 6+7+6+7+5+6+7+7 = 51

> Smallest: `11/11/2011` -- segment count: 2+2+2+2+5+6+2+2 = 23